# how use Softlayer API to authorize an iscsi storage

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, network-storage

I tried to authorize the softlayer endurance storage on a new system, using this command

```
curl -v -i -X POST -d '{"parameters": [{"id": [IP ADDRESS ID]}]}' -u "[USERNAME]:[APIKEY]" https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[STORAGE ID]/allowAccessFromIpAddress.jso
```

I followed the instruction in the link, but it doesn't work.
https://sldn.softlayer.com/it/blog/sjanowiak/how-use-softlayer-api-authorize-guest-vms-iscsi-storage

The console returns this error. (Obviously I put the correct values in the parameters)

```
{"error":"SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccesstFromVirtualGuestList is not implemented.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented"}
```

How can I use the SoftLayer API to authorize a VMs to use the iSCSI Storage?
Is there a funcion with the python service `SoftLayer.ISCSIManager(client)`?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some suggestions that may help you:

- The “network storage” and VSI/Bar Metal/Subnet must to be located in the same location/datacenter.

These requests help us to get available items can be authorized to an specific “network storage” as we can see in the Portal:

To get valid available subnets with associated IP addresses, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/ getAllowableSubnets?objectMask=mask[id,networkIdentifier,cidr,subnetType,ipAddresses[id,ipAddress]]
Method: GET
```

To get valid available virtual guests, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/[storage_id]/ getAllowableVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName] Method: GET
```

Available Bar metal:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getAllowableHardware
Method: GET
```

**References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/getAllowableVirtualGuests
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/getAllowableSubnets
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/getAllowableHardware

It seems to not be a function to authorize network storage using ISCSI Manager. But below are some examples using python client.

**Python examples:**

Using: **SoftLayer_Network_Storage:: allowAccessFromIpAddress**

```
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Set the server id that you wish to allow.
ipAddressId = 20636706
iscsiId = 8393467

# Set up your API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    # The expected result after executing the script is: true
    # To get valid Ip address, execute:
    # https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[Storage_id]/getAllowableSubnets?objectMask=mask[id,networkIdentifier,cidr,subnetType,ipAddresses[id,ipAddress]]
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].allowAccessFromIpAddress({"id":ipAddressId},id=iscsiId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to allow the access to ISCSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Using: **SoftLayer_Network_Storage:: allowAccessFromVirtualGuest**

```
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Set the server id that you wish to allow.
vsiId = 14388437
iscsiId = 8393467

# Set up your API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    # The expected result after executing the script is: true
    # To get valid Virtual Guest ids, execute:
    # https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getAllowableVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName]
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].allowAccessFromVirtualGuest({"id":vsiId},id=iscsiId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to allow the access to ISCSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Using: **SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::allowAccessToNetworkStorage**

```
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Set the server id that you wish to allow.
serverId = 14388435
iscsiId = 8393467

# Set up your API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    # The expected result after executing the script is: true
    result = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].allowAccessToNetworkStorage({"id":iscsiId},id=serverId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to allow the access to ISCSI faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

**References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromVirtualGuest
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHardware
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/allowAccessToNetworkStorage
>
> https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python
>
> https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/python
>
> https://softlayer.github.io/python/

**EDIT**

**I was able to reproduce the same problem using “Endurance Replica”.**
This is a python example to authorize a virtual Guest:

```
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Set the server id that you wish to allow.
vsiId = 15571333
storageId = 6550721
objectType = "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"

# Set up your API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    # To get valid Virtual Guest ids, execute:
    # https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getAllowableVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName]
    result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].allowAccessFromHostList([{"id":vsiId,"objectType": objectType}],id=storageId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to allow the access to network Storage faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

If you want to authorize **“Virtual Guest”,“IpAddress” or “Hardware”**, valid values for “**objectType**” are:
**“SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest “,”SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress”, ”SoftLayer_Hardware”** respectively.

Reference:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList

Regards.

Comment: @LuisLambertoLocke, finally, I was able to reproduce the same problem than you. I tried to authorize an "Endurance Replica". I added an script using "SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccessFromHostList" that works successfully for this case. Please review the "EDIT" section of answer. If you are still having the same problem using this last script, please open a SoftLayer ticket adding the details (i.e. ids, type of storage) in order to isolate the problem (I cannot ask you these details here because they are sensitive information) Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your last edit works properly. Now the endurance is authorized.